# Melting point of objects and food

Tags: everyday-chemistry, boiling-point, melting-point

*What is the melting point of egg yolk?*

Well, generally, when we break an egg, the yolk is in liquid state. After we pour it on a pan, the egg starts to cook and it hardens. My question is, can an egg melt/boil ?

What are the conditions to be imposed?

Comment: Most foods never melt. Instead, they _decompose_.

Comment: @IvanNeretin that does mean that the ***egg*** does not has a definite melting point? since it'll split up?

Comment: That's right, it doesn't melt at all.

Comment: Defined melting point requires pure substance or in some cases well defined mixture of few components, which do not decompose at melting temperature. Egg yolk is not such a case.

Comment: Egg yolk is a complex mixture including a lot of proteins. Heating proteins does not melt them, it causes them to denature or unfold. Once denatured, the proteins interact to form a gel-like solid. If you continue to heat up the solid, it will burn.

Answer (score 2):

As Poutnik said, the melting point is well defined for pure substances. In the case of egg yolk, it is not a pure substance and also when you heat it, some molecules decompose. So we can't measure or even define a melting point for it. Also, the temperature is not constant, when the egg is melting.

A substances' phase doesn't get influenced only by temperature. Maybe it is strange that heating the egg yolk in a pan, makes it to behave like a solid. Actually, some complex changes in intermolecular forces are getting done.

If you want to cause an egg yolk to melt, I think that the only work to do is to heat it under the normal pressure.